# How to setup user groups based on Active Directory in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to create user groups using Active Directory id's and then assign roles in Jenkins? Instead of using Jenkins default user name management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Go to Jenkins' *configuration* - *Access Control* - *Security Realm*.

Choose LDAP or Delegate to servlet container (depends on where you want to put your LDAP config and how your Jenkins is running) and fill you LDAP informations.

Then in *Authorization* part you can select a mode which will ask the LDAP for rights.
You can use user's login or LDAP groups to define the rights.

Comment: Will Active directory works with LDAP?

Comment: Yes, I have it working in my company.